# invalid syntax when trying to set number of decimals

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am using Python 3.3.2 and I am trying to set the number of decimals after an arithmetic operation but it keeps throwing me SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks!

```
exampleInt = 123.456789
print({:.2f}.format(exampleInt)
```

I keep getting the error at the colon from the Python shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:.2f` is not a valid literal. You want a **format string**, and string literals need quotes:

```
In [1]: exampleInt = 123.456789

In [2]: print('{:.2f}'.format(exampleInt))
123.46
```

Also, Delgan is right and a closing parenthesis is missing in your example, but the Python shell will just continue the line in this case, rather than raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the print parenthesis, right?

Comment: that's not it. but yeah I did forget to close it. Thanks for pointing that out!